# How to display Image dynamically on UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I am working on Displaying a screen which is consist of HTML table and Image, an HTML table is fully dynamic.

**Code working process**

When user is loading a page (With URL) I am rendering a HTML table in different parts which means that page is loaded. I am Getting all the table data in 'JSON' format at once and then showing 3-3 rows at a time on `UI` in the gap(Interval) of `3 seconds` When full table is loaded Then I am showing The Image for some time and after that again loading Table and showing image once table is loaded, So it is working fine,Now what I am trying to do is Show the Image dynamically

**What I am trying to do**

Currently I am doing it like `<img src="Image/Counter A/CounterA1.jpg" alt="Some Image" width="460" height="345">` because there was only one Image to Show in folder, but now `Counter A` has two Images or 3 or whatever it may be So When Page is loading I am getting the Which Image is to be loaded in object like this `var images = {"Counter A":["CounterA1.jpg", "CounterA2.jpg"]}` for Counter A there are Two Images similarly for other counters also, SO what I am trying to do is Load table first then, When loading table completed trying to show **first Image than again load table than show Image 2**
That's why I have Images link inside an array, my only Issue is to show one Image at a Time

**Working process**

Table loading -> after 3seconds -> next 3 rows of table until the last page of table -> show Image1 (CounterA1.jpg) -> load  table again -> show Image2(CounterA2.jpg) ->then again table -> then again Image1 because there are only two Images

I have already done showing HTML table and showing Image with only one Image and statically now I want to do That dynamically

```js
var tableValue = [{
  "Item Name": "MANCHOW  V SOUP",
  "SellingPrice": 100
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF GREEN APPLE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF GREEN APPLE30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "BOMBAY SAPHIRE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 472
}, {
  "Item Name": "BOMBAY SAPHIRE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLUE RIBBAND 750",
  "SellingPrice": 877
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLUE RIBBAND 60",
  "SellingPrice": 78
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 248
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 585
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "OLD MONK 180",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "OLD MONK 90",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "OLD MONK 60",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "OLD MONK 30 ",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "DON ANGEL 750",
  "SellingPrice": 466
}, {
  "Item Name": "DON ANGEL 30",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "SAUZA SILVER 700",
  "SellingPrice": 615
}, {
  "Item Name": "SAUZA SILVER 30",
  "SellingPrice": 270
}, {
  "Item Name": "LIME WATER",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "PACKEGED WATER 1L",
  "SellingPrice": 39
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 650",
  "SellingPrice": 900
}, {
  "Item Name": "Chole Kulche",
  "SellingPrice": 80
}, {
  "Item Name": "Butter Nan",
  "SellingPrice": 65
}, {
  "Item Name": "Dhai",
  "SellingPrice": 20
}, {
  "Item Name": "Rice",
  "SellingPrice": 55
}, {
  "Item Name": "Plain rice",
  "SellingPrice": 30
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 650",
  "SellingPrice": 900
}, {
  "Item Name": "Chole Kulche",
  "SellingPrice": 80
}, {
  "Item Name": "Butter Nan",
  "SellingPrice": 65
}, {
  "Item Name": "Dhai",
  "SellingPrice": 20
}, {
  "Item Name": "Rice",
  "SellingPrice": 55
}, {
  "Item Name": "Plain rice",
  "SellingPrice": 30
}]

interval = '';
var images = {
  CounterA: ["CounterA1.jpg", "CounterA2.jpg"]
} // Images to be load on UI
initTable(tableValue);

function initTable(tableValue) {
  addTable(tableValue)
  interval = window.setInterval(showRows, 3000); // seting interval to show table in parts
}




function hideImage() {
  $("#displayImage").show(); //show Image and hide table
  $("#DisplayTable").hide();

  setTimeout(function() {
    initTable(tableValue);
  }, 3000);
}





function showRows() {
  // Any TRs that are not hidden and not already shown get "already-shown" applies
  if ($(".hidden:lt(3)").length > 0) { //checking is it is the last page or not
    $("#displayImage").hide(); //showing table hiding image
    $("#DisplayTable").show();
    $("tr:not(.hidden):not(.already-shown)").addClass("already-shown");
  } else {
    $("tr:not(.hidden):not(.already-shown)").addClass("already-shown");

    hideImage();

    clearInterval(interval); //if last then clearing time interval and calling the function again 
  }

  $(".hidden:lt(3)").removeClass("hidden"); // this one is to hide previous  rows and show next 
}

function addTable(tableValue) {
  var $tbl = $("<table />", {
      "class": "table fixed"
    }),
    $tb = $("<tbody/>"),
    $trh = $("<tr/>");

  var split = Math.round(tableValue.length / 4);
  for (i = 0; i < split; i++) {
    $tr = $("<tr/>", {
      class: "hidden "
    });

    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      $.each(tableValue[split * j + i], function(key, value) {
        if (typeof(value) === "number") {
          $("<td/>", {
            "class": "text-right color" + (j + 1)
          }).html(value).appendTo($tr);
        } else {
          $("<td/>", {
            "class": "text-left color" + (j + 1)
          }).html(value).appendTo($tr);
        }

      });
    }
    $tr.appendTo($tb);
  }
  $tbl.append($tb);
  $("#DisplayTable").html($tbl);
  var images = {
    "Counter A": ["CounterA1.jpg", "CounterA2.jpg"]
  } // Images to be load on UI

  for (var key in images) {

    var imageList = images[key];
    console.log(imageList.length)
    for (i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
      console.log(imageList[i])
      var img = $('<img />').attr({
        'src': 'Image/' + key + '/' + imageList[i], // this one is displaying Image one below other
        'alt': 'Some Image',
        'width': 90 + "%",
        'height': 680
      }).appendTo('#displayImage');
    }

  }
}
```

```css
tbody>tr>td {
  white-space: normal;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .9em;
}

td:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(4),
td:nth-child(6),
td:nth-child(8) {
  width: 85px;
  max-width: 85px;
  height: 63px
}

.fixed {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.color1 {
  background: #4AD184;
}

.color2 {
  background: #EA69EF;
}

.color3 {
  background: #E1A558;
}

.color4 {
  background: #F4F065;
}

.hidden,
.already-shown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="DisplayTable"></div>
<div id="displayImage" style="display: none">

</div>
```

I have commented out all the lines in my `JS` code for better Understanding, here as you can see in my uploaded picture `image` is common folder so I can set it  manually at `src` and counter and their Image I am getting like this `var images = {"Counter A":["CounterA1.jpg", "CounterA2.jpg"]}`

**Edit**

i have added below code

```
        var images = {"Counter A":["CounterA1.jpg","CounterA2.jpg"]} // Images to be load on UI

            for (var key in images) {

            var imageList = images[key];
             console.log(imageList.length)
             for (i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) 
                 {
                 console.log(imageList[i])
                 var img = $('<img />').attr({
                        'src': 'Image/'+key+'/'+imageList[i] , // this one is displaying Image one below other
                        'alt': 'Some Image',
                        'width': 90+"%",
                        'height':680
                    }).appendTo('#displayImage'); 
                 }

            }
```

I have done bit more I think I am near to get the expected result, The issue is it is showing Image one below other which is not true what I am trying to do is when there are Two Images then table --> Image1, table --> Image2 but here after table both Image are rendering one below other please check my snippet

This is how my Image is rendering [image: Check this]

And [image: This]

[image: My Image Folder]

Comment: To confirm, you want to display the content of the table, like a slide show, then show an image, then cycle through the table content again, then show another image. Repeating this for a specific set of images. Is that correct?

Comment: @Twisty Yup and the slide show an all I have already done no need to do that, just trying to do above, you have understood it correctly

Comment: how do you want it to cycle through the images and how will you know the names of the images?

Comment: @Twisty `var images = {
  CounterA: ["CounterA1.jpg", "CounterA2.jpg"]
}` i am getting Images name in an object of arrays you can check my code

Comment: @Twisty here I am having Two images under `Counter A` so two time it will cycle and show image one by one after table loading as you understood, then again table Image1 then table image2 like this

Comment: if you check `imageContainer`, it is an array. You can't concatenate an array in a string hoping that multiple strings will be created or something like that. Do `console.log('Image/' + imageContainer + '/CounterA1.jpg')` and see what ar you actually getting.

Comment: If you want to cycle through them you should understand timers and callbacks. Is not an easy work for a newbie actually, and here people usually will not write the code for you if you understand nothing about what you want to achieve. I recommend you to read a tutorial about "setInterval/setTimeout" and if is not clear enough, read something about javascript callbacks.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález hey after console.log I am getting `Image/Counter A/CounterA1.jpg` and it is working fine

Comment: Don't get me wrong, the question is really nice detailed and formatted, but we are here to help programmers understand what they are trying to achieve, not to write their code.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález hey I am using `setInterval` as you can check my code, my only issue is to loop through the Image to show one by one, currently I am only able to show one

Comment: I can't see any setInterval in your code. I just see an array with `Object.keys()`. Please share your actual code because as far as I can see, you are concatenating an array created with `Object.keys()`. I don't see any tryout to cycle.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I am not saying to write my code, as you can see in my edit it is working fine when I am using for one Image but here as you see `var images = { CounterA: ["CounterA1.jpg", "CounterA2.jpg"] }` I have 2 images for Counter A but able to show one only, that's my issue

Comment: Oh shiet, sorry. I don't saw the code snippet. My fault!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

I have introduced a new function to format image in `HTML`. and then got its length and loop introduced a `cnt`(count) variable and made it to increment. and used modulo to find the number and repeated the images.

```js
var imgLen = 0;
var cnt = 0;

var tableValue = [{
    "Item Name": "MANCHOW  V SOUP",
    "SellingPrice": 100
}, {
    "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF GREEN APPLE 60",
    "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
    "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF GREEN APPLE30",
    "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
    "Item Name": "BOMBAY SAPHIRE 750",
    "SellingPrice": 472
}, {
    "Item Name": "BOMBAY SAPHIRE 30",
    "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
    "Item Name": "BLUE RIBBAND 750",
    "SellingPrice": 877
}, {
    "Item Name": "BLUE RIBBAND 60",
    "SellingPrice": 78
}, {
    "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 750",
    "SellingPrice": 248
}, {
    "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 180",
    "SellingPrice": 585
}, {
    "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 60",
    "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
    "Item Name": "OLD MONK 180",
    "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
    "Item Name": "OLD MONK 90",
    "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
    "Item Name": "OLD MONK 60",
    "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
    "Item Name": "OLD MONK 30 ",
    "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
    "Item Name": "DON ANGEL 750",
    "SellingPrice": 466
}, {
    "Item Name": "DON ANGEL 30",
    "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
    "Item Name": "SAUZA SILVER 700",
    "SellingPrice": 615
}, {
    "Item Name": "SAUZA SILVER 30",
    "SellingPrice": 270
}, {
    "Item Name": "LIME WATER",
    "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
    "Item Name": "PACKEGED WATER 1L",
    "SellingPrice": 39
}, {
    "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 650",
    "SellingPrice": 900
}, {
    "Item Name": "Chole Kulche",
    "SellingPrice": 80
}, {
    "Item Name": "Butter Nan",
    "SellingPrice": 65
}, {
    "Item Name": "Dhai",
    "SellingPrice": 20
}, {
    "Item Name": "Rice",
    "SellingPrice": 55
}, {
    "Item Name": "Plain rice",
    "SellingPrice": 30
}, {
    "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 650",
    "SellingPrice": 900
}, {
    "Item Name": "Chole Kulche",
    "SellingPrice": 80
}, {
    "Item Name": "Butter Nan",
    "SellingPrice": 65
}, {
    "Item Name": "Dhai",
    "SellingPrice": 20
}, {
    "Item Name": "Rice",
    "SellingPrice": 55
}, {
    "Item Name": "Plain rice",
    "SellingPrice": 30
}]


interval = '';
var images = {
    CounterA: ["CounterA1.jpg", "CounterA2.jpg"]
} // Images to be load on UI
initTable(tableValue);

function initTable(tableValue) {
    addTable(tableValue)
    showRows();
    interval = window.setInterval(showRows, 1000); // seting interval to show table in parts
}




function hideImage() {
    var imgno = (cnt%imgLen)+1;
    $("#displayImage img").css("display","none");
    $("#displayImage img:nth-child("+imgno+")").css("display","block")

    $("#displayImage").show(); //show Image and hide table
    $("#DisplayTable").hide();

    setTimeout(function () {
        initTable(tableValue);
    }, 1000);
    cnt++;
}





function showRows() {
    // Any TRs that are not hidden and not already shown get "already-shown" applies
    if ($(".hidden:lt(3)").length > 0) { //checking is it is the last page or not
        $("#displayImage").hide(); //showing table hiding image
        $("#DisplayTable").show();
        $("tr:not(.hidden):not(.already-shown)").addClass("already-shown");
    } else {
        $("tr:not(.hidden):not(.already-shown)").addClass("already-shown");

        hideImage();

        clearInterval(interval); //if last then clearing time interval and calling the function again 
    }

    $(".hidden:lt(3)").removeClass("hidden"); // this one is to hide previous  rows and show next 
}

function addTable(tableValue) {
    var $tbl = $("<table />", {
        "class": "table fixed"
    }),
        $tb = $("<tbody/>"),
        $trh = $("<tr/>");

    var split = Math.round(tableValue.length / 4);
    for (i = 0; i < split; i++) {
        $tr = $("<tr/>", {
            class: "hidden "
        });

        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            $.each(tableValue[split * j + i], function (key, value) {
                if (typeof (value) === "number") {
                    $("<td/>", {
                        "class": "text-right color" + (j + 1)
                    }).html(value).appendTo($tr);
                } else {
                    $("<td/>", {
                        "class": "text-left color" + (j + 1)
                    }).html(value).appendTo($tr);
                }

            });
        }
        $tr.appendTo($tb);
    }
    $tbl.append($tb);
    $("#DisplayTable").html($tbl);

}

imageFormatter();

function imageFormatter() {

    var images = {
        "Counter A": ["CounterA1.jpg", "CounterA2.jpg"],
        "Counter B": ["CounterB1.jpg", "CounterB2.jpg"]
    } // Images to be load on UI

    for (var key in images) {

        var imageList = images[key];
        for (i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
            var img = $('<img />').attr({
                'src': 'Image/' + key + '/' + imageList[i], // this one is displaying Image one below other
                'alt': key + '/' + imageList[i],
                'width': 90 + "%",
                'height': 680
            }).appendTo('#displayImage');
        }

    }
    imgLen = $("#displayImage img").length;
}
```

```css
tbody>tr>td {
  white-space: normal;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .9em;
}

td:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(4),
td:nth-child(6),
td:nth-child(8) {
  width: 85px;
  max-width: 85px;
  height: 63px
}

.fixed {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.color1 {
  background: #4AD184;
}

.color2 {
  background: #EA69EF;
}

.color3 {
  background: #E1A558;
}

.color4 {
  background: #F4F065;
}

.hidden,
.already-shown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="DisplayTable"></div>
<div id="displayImage" style="display:none">

</div>
```

Comment: wait sir let me try it

Comment: Sir on first go it is not showing any Image but in second go it is showing but only first one, when I load the page after table renders then no image then again table renders then Image one then table then again blank

Comment: increase your timeout value and check. because It is working in the above snippet right? or the above snipper too has the same issue?

Comment: snippet has same issue, please check on first go it show nothing then in next loop when intTable is called then it shows `alt` value some Image

Comment: `var images = {
           "Counter A": ["CounterA1.jpg", "CounterA2.jpg"],           
       }` it is only showing CounterA1.jpg not CounterA2.jpg

Comment: hey please check my post once please  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56560534/how-to-reload-ajax-call-function-in-given-time

Comment: sure sir take your time, as you have helped me a lot in this that's why I am asking you